# Nginx loadbalancer https

Tags: nginx, tomcat, load-balancing, https

I'm running into problems when serving https via nginx as a load balancer. I have the following config:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  sub.domain.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/[cert].crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.[cert].com.key;
    ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_ciphers '[...]'

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/tls/certs/dhparams.pem;


    location /application { proxy_pass http://server0; }

    location / {
            return 301 http://www.domain.com;
    }
```

}

And I'm serving a site running on a tomcat on "server0". Sometimes, not always, I get mixed content errors in the browser were requests have been sent over as http instead of https. I'm having problems reproducing the errors in in a concise manner since it sometimes works and sometimes not at all.

Any clues on how to proceed in diagnosing this?

Edit: No coded calls to http are made.

Comment: Do you have a `server` for port 80 that redirects everything to port 443?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your calls are going to `server0`, so are on `/application/<something>` then one possible source of this issue is if the web pages served by `server0` contain references to static resources and are fetched via `http` and not `https`.

Look with the developer tools of the browser. With Chrome, on the network tab you can see all the individual calls made by the browser to fetch additional resources as it parses the HTML from top to bottom, and you could perhaps spot what content came over unsecure `http` calls.

That is not the fault of the load balancer but rather of the implementation of the web app.

Comment: Ah yes that is of course the right answer to my badly asked question but in this case I left out the important part that I've made sure that no references to http resources are to be find in the project. I'll edit this into the original question. Thanks for answering!

Comment: How exactly did you make sure there are no references with `http://` URLs?